# Create Bulk XML from template for POST request using gatling/scala

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

I want to send bulk xml to my soap request body. I want to know is there any way to generate them dynamically through Gatling/Scala
This is how I am doing

> private val request=exec(   http("Post request to create")
>       .post("/endPoint")
>       .headers(Utils.soapHeaders)
>       .body(ElFileBody("requestbody/ids.xml"))
>       .check(status.is(Utils.successStatus)) )
>
> private val feedId = Iterator.continually(   Map(
>         "id" -> Random.alphanumeric.take(13).mkString,
>         "transactionId" -> Random.alphanumeric.take(14).mkString
>       )   )
>
> val scnPostVehicleAsn=Utils.createScenario("soapService", feedId,
>   request)

and requestbody/ids.xml has the template with dynamic values ${transactionId} & ${id}.

So Is there any way to dynamically generate xml based on the template, I am not looking for repeat functionality.
 Just generate xml once before execution and pass it and later I will make rest calls to validate them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I have created a list of random number and passed it to xml directly

> val randomNumbers =
>   List.fill(number)(prefix.concat(Random.alphanumeric.take(13).mkString))
>   {    randomNumbers.map( i => i }

Then,

> val file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")
>   +"/performance-tests/src/test/resources/requestBody/ids.xml") val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
>   bw.write(VehicleAsns.toString()) bw.close()